# Flutter: How to display post from Firestore one by one?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have posts on Firestore, each post contains an image. I want to display the posts one by one. When the user tap a button, an other post is shown. I don't want to show the same post twice to the same user.

What is the best way to do it?

I tried to fetch the last 20 posts to put them in a List of Post (where Post is a class), then deleting the Posts already seen from the List. But every time that I refresh, the same posts are shown. Maybe with a StreamBuilder or a FutureBuilder but I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with deleting the posts already seen from the list, you shouldn't do that. Try fetch every seen posts to a list and save it locally with SharedPreferences, then show only posts that has not been seen by user.

Comment: Thank you I didn’t think about it, I will try. But how can I wait for the list to be filled before displaying it? At the moment I’m forced to refresh manually because the widget is build while the list is empty.

Comment: If everytime user see a post, the post will be in the list of seen posts for an example. Don't delete the post that has been seen, let the list be the mark for seen posts. So when you refresh manually, unseen posts will appear.